# How to sort an array in a way that if a condition is met the contents get sorted first?

Tags: arrays, sorting, lua

I need to sort an array of orders so that the ones already on delivery get put at the end of the list so to put the unfinished orders on the top.
The variable `state` is what i wanted to sort on. If the variable is 0 the contents should have a higher priority than where the state is 1.

Here is a simplification of what i need:

input array:

```lua
{{state=1,...},{state=0,...},{state=0,...},{state=0,...},{state=1,...}}
```

=>

output array:

```lua
{{state=0,...},{state=0,...},{state=0,...},{state=1,...},{state=1,...}}
```

I tried table.sort and some other methods but it didn't fit what i needed or didn't do what i wanted it to do.

Comment: `table.sort` should be correct; please demonstrate exactly what you tried using a [example], and in which specific way it "didn't fit what i needed or didn't do what i wanted it to do".

Answer (score 2):

`table.sort(arr, function(a, b) return a.state < b.state end)` works fine to sort `arr` in non-descending order based on the `state` field of each entry. How did you try to use `table.sort`?

Comment: Ah! Thanks for solving my issue, it seems i've passed an incorrect function.
I don't remember what it was, because i deleted the function from the code since it didn't help at all.